# c# basic memory reading

Tags: c#, memory

okay i give up on strings , i dont know i dont get any value but thats ok for now.

i want to read a simple 4byte int value. i searched in the memory for an exact value of 42 i took the first address.

i already know that the array size has to be 4. but i get realy crazy values.

like -12732139

so i wrote a for loop that tells me the values which are stored inside the byte array

```
for (int j = 0; j < bytes.Length; ++j ) {
                 svalue += "+" + bytes[j];
           }
```

i get realy strange numbers out of it

```
216 184 93 255 // these are stored inside the bytearray which should be 42 dec.
```

i guess something went really wrong ?

i read those values with

```
ReadProcessMemory(readHandle, ((IntPtr)baseAddress + 0x000D3A10), bytes, (UIntPtr)4, ref rw);


int test = BitConverter.ToInt32(new_bytes,0);
```

any ideas ?

// OLD
My full code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    Process[] iexp = Process.GetProcessesByName("iexplore");
    if (iexp.Length == 0) {
        listBox1.Items.Add("NOT FOUND");
    }
    Process internet = iexp[0];
    uint baseAddress = (uint)internet.MainModule.BaseAddress.ToInt32();
    IntPtr readHandle = OpenProcess(0x0010, false, (uint)internet.Id);
    byte[] bytes = new byte[24];
    uint rw = 0;
    uint size=sizeof(int);

    ReadProcessMemory(readHandle, ((IntPtr)baseAddress + 0x00581CCE), bytes, 
        (UIntPtr)24, ref rw);
    string sname= Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
    ReadProcessMemory(readHandle, (IntPtr)baseAddress + 0x00528744, bytes, 
        (UIntPtr)size, ref rw);
    int someNumber = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);

    listBox1.Items.Add(sname);
    listBox1.Items.Add(someNumber);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function is just to read plain memory. It does not have the concept of types and therefore does not know what strings are or even that they have a length. If you reach into a process' memory to read things you are on your own. You need to know exactly what you want to read and what to make of the data.

Although as you are trying to read a string: You could try and read the bytes in a loop and stop when you encounter a 0 byte which is what is used by C to denoted the end of a string (NULL terminated strings).

Comment: ahhhhhhhh that makes sense ! 
okay i try this now.

but .. iam a little bit confused. do i still need the com thing ?

Comment: @MaikKlein: The solution by casperOne is a different way to access the running instance of IE. So you can either try to read the process memory directly as you indicated in your question or you can try caspers suggestion and use COM interop to access IE that way and get the data you want.

Comment: what would you recommend me to do ?
stick with my approach or switching to Interop?
are their restrictions with the interop method?

btw thank you for your patients :)

Comment: @MaikKlein The memory reading is more powerful but is also more cumbersome and less reliable. The interop API is more stable but might not give you the information you want. Without knowing what you want to do it's hard to say.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to [connect to a running instance of Internet Explorer through automation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/176792).

You'll have to use [COM interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kew41ycz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), but the solution above will allow you to access any running instance of Internet Explorer in the current desktop session and from there you can access the full window/document object models.

Comment: so i have to read something like this ?
http://www.amazon.com/NET-COM-Complete-Interoperability-Guide/dp/067232170X

Comment: @MaikKlein: Not necessarily, while it would help, yes, there are many COM interop resources on the web which. The link I posted is a good place to start.

Comment: i think iam not the first one who wants to read from the memory.

do you know if there are examples of reading basic information out of programs with c# ?

that would give me a better overview for what i should look. atm its very confusing for me.
or if its not too much work, could you give me an example of how it is done ? doesnt have to be much. just enough to understand the whole concept

Comment: @MaikKlein: Reading the memory space of other programs is generally a bad thing, there's no guarantee that the addresses you are reading are stable, and it's code that's very, very brittle.  Generally, you should look for APIs that the application provides and use those.